# Array Sort Method in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I changed around the first System.out.println statement, but i still see nothing!!! The only thing i get is Build Successful, but no output for user input!!

```
  //initializes the array to have a limit of 10 numbers inputted
    double[] numbers = new double [10];

    // this loop reads in the numbers inputed from the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
 }

System.out.println("Enter " + numbers.length + " values: ");

    java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);// this is the Array.sort()method

    // this loop sorts the numbers and then prints them
    for(double number : numbers){
        System.out.println(number);
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you screaming? :s

Comment: I've indented your code and added some line breaks so it's easier to follow. I suggest you get used to and follow this style (or similar) *everywhere*.

Comment: Have you determined which line of code fails? Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: For me your program works fine: See https://ideone.com/Z0LizJ

Comment: Sorry for the caps lock, I was trying to have those points highlighted.

Comment: But does the program ever finishes?

Comment: I am using NetBeans, the only thing i get is that the Build was Sucessful!! But i am not recieving any output!!

Comment: You should't get an output if you don't enter an input! Type 10 numbers in the console then hit enter and you'll see. IT WORKS

Answer (score 3):

Your program works, but you maybe don't use it well because you keep seeing *Enter 10 values:* after you enter each number.

Try to move

`System.out.println("Enter " + numbers.length + " values: ");`

to outside the *for* loop. Then enter 10 numbers and you'll see the output.

BTW, your program also works if you don't move it to outside the `for` loop, but.. like you saw, this is misleading.

Next time, use a debugger. It is amazing.. I sometimes even debug a working code.. just because it's amazing :)

Comment: Agree. :-) Debugger reveals stuff we didn't know when coding was done.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting output, just not when you think you should. Because you put `numbers[i] = input.nextDouble()` before your print statement, the console is waiting for input before printing a message. I bet if you run the program, enter a number, and hit enter, you will get the the message you think you should be seeing. The solution is just switch those two lines of code in that `for` loop.

Comment: I am using NetBeans if that helps at all!! But i am still not getting any output!!!

Comment: What does that method look like now?